# How to enable emmet in .astro?

Tags: neovim, emmet, astrojs

https://github.com/withastro/language-tools/tree/main/packages/language-server

I have installed the language server above in neovim.

The language server comes with [`emmet`](https://github.com/withastro/language-tools#features-provided) support, but I can't seem to get it to work.

How can I enable `emmet` in `.astro` files?

Comment: Use their issue tracker.

Answer (score 4):

Open VSCode global settings then search for `emmet`. Scroll to `Emmet: Include Languages` section and click on *Add Item*

[image]

add `astro` on the left and `html` to the right. Restart VSCode and now you can use emmet tab in `.astro` files

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately. Have also noticed that vscode doesn't seem to recognise .astro as any sort of file type (ie there's no astro icon by the files), so it might be that